# Send email with attachment using mailchimp API and Python

Tags: python, email, base64, mailchimp

I try to send an email with attachment with Python using the mailchimp API. In the documentation, https://mailchimp.com/developer/transactional/api/messages/send-using-message-template/, they explain that you can use the parameter `attachments`. I tried with this:

```py
with open('file.pdf','rb') as f:
   d = f.read()
   d = base64.b64encode(d)
   d = d.decode('utf-8')

attachments = [{'content':d,'name':'file.pdf','type':'application/pdf'}]
try:
   response = mailchimp.messages.send_template({"template_name": template,
   "template_content": [],
   "message": msg,
   "attachments":attachments})
```

The email was sent but it didn't have any file.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: I don't see parameter `"attachments"` in your documentation.

Comment: I found `attachments` but inside `message`, not directly in `send_template`.Maybe it has to be `"message": {"text": msg, "attachments":attachments}`